# How to update a property of an object using Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Every Parse `Installation` object instance in my Parse database has a pointer to a specific user. I have a background job that runs for every user, and what I want to do in this part of the background job is to set the respective user `Installation`'s `channel` property to `["yesPush"]`, for push notification targeting purposes.

The way I figured I would do it is by querying for the specific `Parse.Installation` instance, and then setting its channels property. This doesn't seem to be working however. I'm trying to follow the guidelines in the [Parse Cloud Code Docs](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-modifysave), but it's either not the correct use case, or I'm not following it correctly.

**Code:**

```
var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
installationQuery.equalTo('userId', parentUser);

installationQuery.find().then(function(results) {
  return Parse.Object.set('channels', ["yesPush"]);
});
```

Comment: Where is `parentUser` set? why are you using a `return` call inside your find? Why are you using `find` instead of `first` if you expect at most 1 match? Why aren't you calling `set()` on the actual object itself? Why aren't you calling `save()` or `saveInBackground()`?

Comment: `parentUser` is an argument called by the encompassing function, it's used in different parts of the fxn without any problems, so I don't think thats the issue. I thought a return had to be used there, and using `find` instead of `first` was a silly mistake. How would I call `set()` on the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it is as follows:

```
// for every User
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.each(function(user) {
  var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  installationQuery.equalTo('userId', user);

  return installationQuery.first().then(function(installation) {
    installation.set('channels', ['yesPush']);
    return installation.save();
  });
}).then(function() {
  status.success();
}, function(error) {
  status.error(error.message);
});
```

The `each()` function is how you process large sets of data in a job. If you are performing other async tasks inside it you need to return their promise.

The `first()` function is much faster and easier if we only expect one record.

I am calling `set()` on the actual `installation` object returned by `first()`.

I am returning the `save()` promise to allow promise chaining.